# How can I isolate one object in the viewport and still have all the lighting and models around it still affecting it?

Tags: 3d-view

I want to isolate one object in the viewport (I know I can do that with "/"), but I want the rest of the lighting and models to still affect it.

I mainly want to use this for texturing certain elements in a big scene. Is there a way to do this or is it a bit of a reach?

Comment: I could write a Python script that assigns a temporary material to all other objects, with Blend Mode set to Alpha Blend, and Alpha set to 0.0: https://i.imgur.com/zu36q8C.png as well as make those objects unselectable. It could also hide cameras. You would still see light objects as on the screenshot.

Comment: Well...That would be simply INCREDIBLE ! Also an alternative (not sure if easier/less taxing on system ? or not ? )
I wonder if instead of assigning a temp material maybe doing this : 1-Select object 2-Invert selection 3-Object properties 4-deselect camera in Ray visibility 5-Copy to selected. AND then doing the reverse to bring them back to normal again

Comment: I'm not sure what are the upsides of disabling Ray Visibility -> Camera, but the downside is it only works in Cycles...

Comment: @markusvonbroady oopps You’re actually right hah totally forgot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python script

As promised. After running the script, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> to hide/unhide. Everything except the active object, lights and meshes is hidden. Meshes other than the active object have their materials replaced with a temporary material using *Alpha Blend* and *Alpha=0*. If there's no material slot, it is created. All data is saved to a textblock, so you can hide other objects, save the file, return to it later, and unhide the objects. **However**, messing with material slots of *"hidden"* meshes, or renaming them, will hurt you.

[image]

```
import bpy, json

shortcut_key = "NUMPAD_SLASH"
shortcut_modifiers = {"alt": True}
save_name = "hidden"

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
addon_keymaps = []  # store keymaps here to access after registration

class CUSTOM_LOCAL_OT_With_Light(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Make other objects invisible, but still affect light paths
    https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/226679/60486 """
    bl_idname = "custom_local.with_light"
    bl_label = "Local view with light still affected by hidden objects"
    
    def make_invisible_material(self):
        name = "Temp.Invisible.Material"
        m = D.materials.get(name)
        if not m:
            m = D.materials.new(name)
            m.use_nodes = True
            m.blend_method = 'BLEND'
            m.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Alpha'].default_value = 0.0
        return m
            
    def hide(self):
        engine = bpy.context.scene.render.engine
        invisible_mat = self.make_invisible_material()
        objs = []
        mats_with_fake_user = set()
        
        to_hide = (o for o in C.scene.objects
                   if o.type != 'LIGHT' and not o.hide_get() and o is not C.active_object)
        for o in to_hide: 
            entry = {"name": o.name}
            objs.append(entry)
            if o.type != 'MESH':
                o.hide_set(True)
                continue
            if o.hide_select:
                entry["was_unselectable"] = True
            else:
                o.hide_select = True
            if engine == 'CYCLES':
                if o.cycles_visibility.camera:
                    entry["camera_ray"] = True
                    o.cycles_visibility.camera = False
                continue
            entry["materials"] = []
            if not o.material_slots:  # no slot
                entry["slot_added"] = True
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add({'object': o})
                o.material_slots[0].material = invisible_mat
                continue
            for slot in o.material_slots:
                mat = slot.material
                slot.material = invisible_mat
                if not mat:  # empty slot
                    entry["materials"].append("")
                    continue
                if mat.use_fake_user:
                    mats_with_fake_user.add(mat.name)
                mat.use_fake_user = True
                entry["materials"].append(mat.name)
        return {"materials_with_fake_user": list(mats_with_fake_user), "objects": objs}
                
    
    def unhide(self, data):
        for entry in data["objects"]:
            o = D.objects[entry["name"]]
            o.hide_set(False)  # hidden objects were ignored, so all objects saved
                               # are objects hidden by this script
            if "was_unselectable" not in entry:
                o.hide_select = False
            if "camera_ray" in entry:
                o.cycles_visibility.camera = True
            mats = entry.get("materials")
            if mats is None:
                continue
            if "slot_added" in entry:  # remove the added slot
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': o})
            for i, name in enumerate(entry["materials"]):
                mat = D.materials[name] if name else None
                o.material_slots[i].material = mat
                if mat and mat not in data["materials_with_fake_user"]:
                    mat.use_fake_user = False            
    
    def execute(self, context):
        txt = D.texts.get(save_name)
        if txt:
            self.unhide(json.loads(txt.as_string()))
            D.texts.remove(txt)
        else:
            txt = D.texts.new(save_name)
            txt.from_string(json.dumps(self.hide()))
        return {"FINISHED"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CUSTOM_LOCAL_OT_With_Light)
    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View Generic', space_type='VIEW_3D')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(CUSTOM_LOCAL_OT_With_Light.bl_idname, shortcut_key, 'PRESS', **shortcut_modifiers)
    addon_keymaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CUSTOM_LOCAL_OT_With_Light)
    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in addon_keymaps:
        wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(km)
    # clear the list
    del addon_keymaps[:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is Incredible !!! PS:It only works in EEVEE though, is something like this possible with cycles too or not really ? Thank you again!!

Comment: @kay777 oh, so you were right with camera visibility after all. I updated the script, though I were unable to make the floor behind hidden meshes visible in Cycles :(.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new Collection.

With an object selected, press <kbd>M</kbd> -it moves the specific object into the collection.

[image]

Use the *Isolate* icon to turn OFF/ON the main Collection.

[image]

Notes:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking on the *Isolate* icon will set all nested collections
- I moved lights into a solo collection just to make it organised, but you can keep it in a main collection. Lights are not affected.
- Cycles only (so it is useless for texturing)